# Word coined to describe the phenomenon of using an oft-repeated rhetoric to shut down a discussion or debate

Tags: single-word-requests

Some time ago I read about a word that was coined to describe when someone uses a "common sense" style rhetoric to attempt to stifle or shut down further discussion on a topic, but I cannot recall what that word was.

Answer (score 2):

It is a **thought-terminating cliché** [1].

I was incorrect about it being a single word.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought-terminating_clich%C3%A9

Comment: I'd say most cliches are thought-terminating, though.  That's why they're cliche.

Answer (score 0):

this particular tactical fallacy comes under the broad category of ***sophism*** or ***sophistry*** if a single word is required to describe it.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sophism?s=t

Answer (score -1):

"Moot"? As in, "this is a moot point; there's no point of continuing the discussion".

Comment: I remember that it's a coined term, not one I would expect to be found in an any conventional English dictionary.  The phenomenon describes a person's attempts to make the discussion moot, however it is done by repeating a rhetorical and often emotionally-charged phrase that's easily defensible and difficult to attack without taking on the baggage of a stance against the emotional charge.